# Laravel: Select DB error Undefined index or Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, multidimensional-array

First Laravel project. I have a DBController what selects a row from the database after the url (for example the URL is /product/123 then it search for the product which barcode is 123). And I want to make a table about the productdetails on the next page.

**Controller:**

```
class ProductDetailsController extends Controller
{
    public function product($id){
    $product = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id]);;
    return view('productdetails',['product'=>$product]);
    }
}
```

**print_r($product) output:**

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [barcode] => 01233 [brand]
>   => Ismeretlen [supplier] => 1 [type] => Építésianyag [name] => Homok [img] => homok.jpg [wholeprice] => 3000 [price] => 5500 [VAT] => 3
>   [whereis] => U [whereis2] => 1 [count] => 8 [dimension] => m3
>   [threshold] => 1 [lastsell] => [lastbuy] => [lastchange] => 2017-02-23
>   20:56:46 [register] => ) )

If I try `{{ $product->brand }}` I got:

> ErrorException in 20d205ed160f36c734b8252e44ac81bfa0977988.php line 6:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/project/laravel/leltar/resources/views/productdetails.blade.php)

And if I try `{{ $product['brand'] }}` I got:

> ErrorException in 20d205ed160f36c734b8252e44ac81bfa0977988.php line 6:
>   Undefined index: brand (View:
>   /var/www/html/project/laravel/leltar/resources/views/productdetails.blade.php)

What's going wrong?

I learn Laravel from [this PDF](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once check the structure of array it is having 0th index first,

You should get it like,

```
{{$product[0]->brand}}
```

OR

```
$product = DB::table("inventory")->where("barcode", $id)->first();
// and get data as
echo $product->brand;
```

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first method and it's working. I will try the second method, too :) The site needs 8 more minutes before I can accept your answer

Comment: @NeetinSolanki I will accept it but when I click on the checkmark it says, that "You can accept the answer in 3 minutes".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$product = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id])->first();

dd($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do it with eloquent model,Create a modle of inventory like that 
$products=Inventory::where('id',$id)->first();

and you can get brands $products->brand.